# Div with border and top/right, bottom/left transparent edges

Tags: html, css, border, css-shapes

Does anybody knows how to code the border (upper right corner and lower left corner) of the box(image below)? 
Hope you can help me.
Thanks in advance!
[image: Div with border and top/right, bottom/left transparent edges]

This is the HTML

```
<div class="carouselle">
   <div class="carousel-item">
       <div class="xx_b">
          <p>«  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, feugiat delicata liberavisse id   
           cum, no quo maiorum intellegebat, liber regione eu sit. 
            Mea cu case ludus integre, vide viderer eleifend ex mea. His ay 
            diceret, cum et atqui placerat... »</p>
        </div>
         <span class="t_author">Tom Cruz</span>
         <span class="t_occupation">Famous Movie Star</span>
      </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS

```
.carouselle .carousel-item .xx_b:after {
  -moz-border-bottom-colors: none;
  -moz-border-left-colors: none;
  -moz-border-right-colors: none;
  -moz-border-top-colors: none;
  border-color: #eee transparent transparent;
  border-image: none;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  bottom: -20px;
  content: "";
  margin-left: -10px;
  position: absolute;
 }

.carouselle .carousel-item .xx_b {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eee;
  border: 15px solid #cccccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  padding: 50px 150px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
 }
```

Comment: This looks more like a `box-shadow` to me. Are you sure it's supposed to be a `border`?

Comment: use box-shadow + border to get the desired effect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be better to use `box-shadow` to create the above effect instead of pseudo-elements and borders. We would need two box shadows, one for the top and left areas and another (`inset` box shadow) for the right and bottom areas.

The thickness of the bordering areas can be adjusted by modifying the size of the box-shadows.

```css
.carouselle .carousel-item .xx_b {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #eee;
  box-shadow: -15px -15px 0px #cccccc, inset -15px -15px 0px #cccccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0px 30px 10px;
  padding: 50px 150px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="carouselle">
  <div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="xx_b">
      <p>« Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, feugiat delicata liberavisse id cum, no quo maiorum intellegebat, liber regione eu sit. Mea cu case ludus integre, vide viderer eleifend ex mea. His ay diceret, cum et atqui placerat... »</p>
    </div>
    <span class="t_author">Tom Cruz</span>
    <span class="t_occupation">Famous Movie Star</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AlyssaReyes: Glad to be of help mate :)

Answer (score 2):

To get this effect we can combine `border` with `box-shadow`. The `border` attribute will be used for two of the borders (top and right or left, or bottom and right or left), and the `box-shadow` will be used for the other two.

Finally, we'd then need to introduce a margin on the edges which has the shadow to offset our element's width, as `box-shadow` doesn't contribute to the width of the element.

```css
div {
    border-top: 15px solid #cccccc;
    border-right: 15px solid #cccccc;
    box-shadow: 15px 15px 0 1px #cccccc;
    margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
}
```

#### Final Result

[image: Final Result]

#### Demo

```css
div {
  background: #eee;
  height: 100px;
  
  border-top: 15px solid #cccccc;
  border-left: 15px solid #cccccc;
  
  box-shadow: 15px 15px 0 1px #cccccc;
  
  margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an other approach using two overlayed pseudo elements for the background. In the following example, the "borders" are responsive :

```css
p {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 4%;
  text-align: center; color: #fff;
}
p:before,p:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background: grey;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: -1;
}
p:before {
  margin: -0.5% 0 0 -0.5%;
}
p:after {
  margin: 0.5% 0 0 0.5%;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultrices commodo ligula, sed venenatis metus sollicitudin nec. Maecenas vestibulum porttitor tempus.
</p>
```

As commented by [jbutler483](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3436942/jbutler483) the same output can be achieved with one pseudo element and `rgba()` colors for the background transparency :

```css
p{
    width:80%;
    margin:50px auto;
    padding:5% 4% 4% 5%;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
p:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    background:inherit;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    left:0; top:0;
    margin: 1% 0 0 1%;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ultrices commodo ligula, sed venenatis metus sollicitudin nec. Maecenas vestibulum porttitor tempus.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.container {
    width:600px;    
}
p {
    background: #A1A1A1;
    padding:25px;
    font-size:12px;
    box-shadow: -5px -5px 0px #ccc, inset -5px -5px 0px #ccc;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p>« Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, feugiat delicata liberavisse id   
           cum, no quo maiorum intellegebat, liber regione eu sit. 
            Mea cu case ludus integre, vide viderer eleifend ex mea. His ay 
            diceret, cum et atqui placerat... »</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
div {
  background: #eee;
  height: 100px; 
  box-shadow: 7px 7px 0px 7px #cccccc, -7px -7px 0 7px #cccccc;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```